# Passing a secondary event to a nested click event? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Really stuck on this problem I am having.

**The problem :**

I have a button which will trigger a reorder method. This reorder method is dependant on the click event that is binded to the reorder button.

I want to add a confirm step using a overlay, inside the overlay there is a confirm button which will then pass the original button event.

```
'reorder-overlay-confirmation': function (event) {
        var self = this;
        $(self).find('.reorder-confirm-btn').click(function (e, event) {
            e.preventDefault();
           _reorder(event);
        });
    },
```

How can I pass the initial event into the confirmation button.

I tried passing it as an argument but it is null whenever it calls the `_reorder()` method.

How can I pass the first click event as an argument of my second confirmation click event?

**Note :** I cannot use jQuery confirm as there is some overlay functionality existing that I must use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it as extra parameter in the event data so it will be accessed via  `e.data` like :

```
$(self).on('click', '.reorder-confirm-btn', { first_event: event }, function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    _reorder(e.data.first_event);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is that not what you're looking for ?